# which operators are "really truly positive"?

Tags: lie-algebras, operator-theory, operator-norms

Let's say that an operator G on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is "**really truly positive**" iff

$\Vert\exp(-tG) \exp(-tG^*)\Vert_{op}<1$ for all $t>0$

How can we characterize the set of operators G which are really truly positive?  I conjecture that $G$ is really truly positive iff the eigenvalues of $(G+G^*)$ are all nonnegative.  I have yet to find an exception to this rule.  This is obvious if $G$ is normal because in that case $\exp(-tG) \exp(-tG^*) = \exp(-t(G+G^*))$ -- but if $G$ doesn't commute with its adjoint this formula does not hold and so it is harder to try to prove anything.

[[A word on notation used here... Let $\exp(M)$ denote the operator exponential of an operator $M$.   Let $\Vert M\Vert_{op}$ denote the operator norm of $M$.  Let $G^*$ denote the adjoint of an operator $G$.]]

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! I suggest to explicitly mention in the question that you consider an operator *on a Hilbert space*.

Comment: What is the BCH condition?

Comment: The BCH formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) gives an explicit formula for how to compute exp(X)exp(Y).